# How to render an Array to a YAML list with ERB?

Tags: ruby, erb

I am trying to render an Array with ERB to a YAML file.

Input:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

Expected output:

```
  ---
  tags:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

Code:

```
tags:
  <%- @arr.each do |tag| -%>
  - <%= tag %>
  <% end -%>
  - extra-tag
```

This renders the following YAML

```
---
tags:
  - 1 - 2 -3
```

Is there a way to render this properly?

Comment: May I ask what would be wrong with `YAML#dump`? Also are you sure you review your output as text, not as HTML via browser?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by YAML#dump. I am using vi to view the yaml.

Comment: I believe he meant something like `<%= YAML.dump("tags" => @arr).lines[1..-1].join("\n") %>`.  I see no reason why your example would skip linefeeds on the tag line.

Comment: I mean ruby has yaml dumping in standard library, why would you reinvent a wheel?

Comment: Easier to than reindenting + removing the YAML header. There are scenarios where you need to build YAMLs from templates, for example in some apps users can create something like config.erb where they can interpolate ENV's into the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I see in your example is the missing leading `-` from the closing `<% end -%>` (should be `<%- end -%>`).

```
# foo.erb:
<%- @arr = [1,2,3] -%>
tags:
  <%- @arr.each do |tag| -%>
  - <%= tag %>
  <%- end -%>
  - extra tag
```

Output:

```
$ erb -T - foo.erb
tags:
 - 1
 - 2
 - 3
 - extra tag
```

Without the leading `-` the result I get is different from yours:

```
tags:
  - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    - extra tag
```